# How to show amount of times user has logged in using AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am currently attempting to show a full log of how many times a user has logged in using AsyncStorage.

This is because I want to show a pop-up modal when the user logs in for the first time.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Previously, I have been able to show the user details in the console.log, which shows the email and password in a string format.

However, I am unsure on were to go to from there. Would a for loop be the appropriate solution, or is there a method that is already achieves this?

LOGIN SCREEN -

```
_loginUser = async () => {
        const { password, email } = this.state;
        if(email == '' || password == '') {
            alert('Please enter all fields');
        }
        else {
            //save data using AsyncStorage
            let loginArray = {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }

            //key of the item to set
            AsyncStorage.setItem('loginArray',
            JSON.stringify(loginArray));
            console.log(loginArray);

            // const logsInfo = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys('loginArray');
            // console.log(this.setState({ logs: logsInfo }));

            this.setState({
                loading: true
            });

            this._signInAsync();
        }
    }

    _signInAsync = async () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
            });
            this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
        }, 2000);
    };
```

HOMESCREEN -

```
  fetchAllItems = async () => {
    try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        const items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
        this.setState({ userCredentials: items })

        Reactotron.log(this.state.userCredentials);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error, "problemo")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to know how many times a user logged in your App?
For that you can keep a counter in `AsyncStorage`.

In LOGIN SCREEN -,

```
...

    // Count of last logged in
    let count = 0
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("COUNTER");
      if (value !== null) {
        // We have counter!!
        count = parseInt(value) + 1
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data, ie. count = 0
    }

    let loginArray = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      counter: count
    };

    //key of the item to set
    AsyncStorage.setItem("loginArray", JSON.stringify(loginArray));
    AsyncStorage.setItem("COUNTER", JSON.stringify(count));
    console.log(loginArray);

    ...
```

And in HOMESCREEN -,

You will get the total count in `AsyncStorage`.

```
...

//Here you will get the cont
const items = await AsyncStorage.getItem("loginArray")
this.setState({ userCredentials: items })
...
```

`items` contain 'email', 'password' and 'counter'.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the counter showing up in the console, however it is outputting the following after each login attempt: `\\"\\01\\\\\"1\\\"1\\\\"1`.

Comment: Hi, I updated the code. The issue in integer parsing. changed to count = parseInt(value) + 1. Try this.

Comment: Hello, the counter returns "null" after every login whether it is an existing user logging in, or a new user logging in for the first time.